# Python: gettext() issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, gettext, flask-babel

I am using [`flask_babelex`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-BabelEx/) module to translate strings in my project. The  given scenario below is for *English to Japanese* translation:

Here is the actual string:

```
     gettext(
         'The font size to use for the SQL text boxes and editors. '
         'The value specified is in "em" units, in which 1 is the  '
         'default relative font size. For example, to increase the '
         'font size by 20 percent use a value of 1.2, or to reduce '
         'by 20 percent, use a value of 0.8. Minimum 0.1, maximum 10.'
     )
```

It fails at:

```
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_babelex/\__init__.py +534
```

with the following error:

```
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_babelex/__init__.py", line 623, in gettext
    return get_domain().gettext(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_babelex/__init__.py", line 534, in gettext
    return t.ugettext(string) % variables

ValueError: unsupported format character '?' (0x5927) at index 70
```

When I use `pyCharm` to debug the issue this what it shows in Debug window.

[image]

I'm not able to figure out what is wrong here?